# What is the best practice for creating a Dockerfile for different development environments in Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I should create different development environments for developers in Docker.
The plan is to do a Jenkins job that will make new Dockerfiles for each new environment.
After that, Jenkins would make a build of that Dockerfile and make the image on the Docker hub available to developers.

I don't know how good this approach is and if there is a better solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The practice I'm used to is to run an identical Docker image in all environments.  It can be checked into the repository alongside the application source file.  If you need environment-specific settings (for example, the location and credentials for a database) you'd inject those at deployment time, not during an image build.

Comment: David Maze thank you!

Comment: I have a scenario to run same docker image in windows and in linux environments, so in addition to above suggestion to inject settings at deployment time, i also used different base images for different environments in a hierarchy, first to build base and next to build app . eg  -mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803 as base  and mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base. I created a tag for image "docker build dockerFile -t envSpecificImage" and used the "envSpecificImage" in further dockerFiles to build apps